# Are all symbol-wise optimal code Huffman code?

Tags: information-theory

As the title suggests. Basically, I am asking can we use Huffman coding scheme to find all symbol-wise optimal codes given some alphabet and the probability of their occurrences (consider all tie-breaking scenarios).

Comment: " (consider all tie-breaking scenarios)." is something that has been given as indication in your homework : how do you use it (considering that this sentence isn't very clear ...) ?

Comment: What I meant was all possible codes we can obtain by following Huffman coding scheme. Is it just the subset of all optimal symbol-wise codes or it is exactly that

Comment: Please define symbol-wise optimal code. It's not a standard term.

Comment: @kodlu for the definition of symbol-wise coding can refer to this notes: https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~scarlett/CS3236_notes/02-SymbolSource.pdf. By 'symbol-wise optimal' I mean the shortest average length that any symbol-wise codes can possibly achieve.

Comment: so it's just the usual definition of source coding, I never heard that term being used before.